# Handle accessibility when user click on empty area

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uiaccessibility

General scenario: When user clicks on empty area, control does not goto any other place.

My scenario: When user clicks on empty area, control goes to last cell.

Is there any way to handle the empty area click?

- I have already manages `accessibilityElements` array which comprises of needed UI elements only.
- I have kept the `isAccessibilityElement` false to elements which are not needed

This is occuring on one screen only. I researched about it but no solution found yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the accessibilityActivate() of empty area. 
Return true if you wish to modify the default implementation i.e., write your custom code for what needs to be done and then return true.
If you don't want to change the default implementation i e., let the OS decide what happens on double tap of empty area, return false. By default, return type is false.

Read more here 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615165-accessibilityactivate